# How to return a header in excel vlookup and hlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying have two inputs return a value in a header of a table

```
      -     NP    Ba1   Ba2    N     G1    G2
T2    0%    0%    0%    10%   30%   60%   100%
T1    0%    1%    6%    21%   50%   80%   100%
A     0%    2%    12%   32%   72%   90%   100%
B1    0%    2%    22%   62%   82%   95%   100%
B2    0%    5%    45%   75%   95%   100%  100%
```

Assume this is the data:

B2

37%

The result I want it to return is  Ba1.

If either of those change I would need it to find a new result for example:

A

93%

Should return G2.

I am not sure how to have it search down the First column and then move over to the range I want then return the value from the First row.

Any help would be awesome.

I am actually doing the thing in a Google Spreadsheet, so the simpler the better.  I am not familiar with VBAs either, so if I could keep it in excel that would be great.

Comment: I am trying to do a weighted result return.  After some research I found I need to do a match(rand(),{0,0,0,.1,.3..6,1}) in order to get a number. Where the RAND is the actual 37% as in example 1... I could then use a h lookup to get the Header I wanted, but now I am having trouble selecting the Column, T1, and then it auto populating the match with the variables I need

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of some other people here is the answer:-

```
Row\Col  A   B    C     D     E     F     G     H       I   J   K   L
1            -    NP    Ba1   Ba2   N     G1    G2              
2       T2   0%   0%    0%    10%   30%   60%   100%        A   10% Ba2
3       T1   0%   1%    6%    21%   50%   80%   100%        A   93% G2
4       A    0%   2%    12%   32%   72%   90%   100%                
5       B1   0%   2%    22%   62%   82%   95%   100%                
6       B2   0%   5%    45%   75%   95%   100%  100%
```

L2, Copied down:-

```
=LOOKUP($K2,INDEX($A$1:$H$6,MATCH($J2,$A$2:$A$6,0),0),$B$1:$H$1);
```

Reference:- http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/861739-multi-variable-search-table-return-header.html#post4186002